# In Unity, is there a difference between Vector3.down and -Vector3.up?

Tags: unity, vector, raycasting

I've noticed numerous tutorials and examples using something like "transform.up * -1" or "-Vector3.up" instead of simply saying "transform.down" and "Vector3.down".

Is there a good reason for this, or is it simply a style difference?

I'm specifically thinking about downward raycasts, if that matters at all.

Comment: Not really, both cases whether transform (locally) or Vector3 (world) mean the inverse if you change their signs. Although it is better to call for -Vector3.up than (Vector3.up * -1f), because the later needs a multiplication operation. Asides from that, it may be just comodity, pecause it is easier to change code, than to change "up"  for "down", for example.

Comment: Note that while `Vector3.down` exists, `transform.down` does not. (At least, not [according to the docs as of version 2017.3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're equivalent. You can verify via the documentation for [`down`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-down.html) and [`up`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-up.html) respectively.

The choice is thus down to style (or perhaps ignorance of the existence of `down`) and relatively minor, nitpicky sorts of details (like how one could make that case that, for iteration purposes, it may be easier to add or remove the leading `-` to switch between two options).

Answer (score 1):

`Vector3.up` equals to `new Vector3(0, 1, 0)`

`Vector3.down` equals to `new Vector3(0, -1, 0)`

When you do `-Vector3.up` it sets every value to negative value:

```
public static Vector3 operator -(Vector3 vector)
{
    vector.x = -vector.x; 
    vector.y = -vector.y; 
    vector.z = -vector.z;

    return vector;
}
```

Or Unity could also implement it as immutable type and it will do:

```
public static Vector3 operator -(Vector3 vector)
{
    return new Vector3(-vector.x, -vector.y, -vector.z);
}
```

Though, you can do `someVector.y = 10f;`, thus they are not immutable.